# Not able to create ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs

**npx create-react-app myapp**

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
spawn C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin ENOENT

Comment: Do you have Node system variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have create-react-app installed? If it is installed just run create-react-app myapp

Answer (score 0):

Try `yarn` it's an alternative node package manager.
I had similar problems with `npm`

`yarn create react-app app-name`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there could be some fault in your node installation. But before that make sure your npm is of at least 5.2.0 or newer. To update it to the latest do `npm install -g npm`.
If it still doesn't work, you should remove any global installation of create-react-app and retry. At last, I'd try to reinstall Node if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems link there is some error with your npm.
Try cleaning the cache by doing

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and after that run

```
npm cache verify
```

now try creating your reach app by typing

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Even after doing this won't work
do install latest npm again by doing

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```